# Configuring Bittorrent

Tags: mac, internet-connection, port, bittorrent, provider

I have used Bittorrent without problems for the past year.

Then a couple of weeks ago I changed my internet provider (now I have Fastweb.. I live in Italy)

It is *much* faster, but Bittorent does not work anymore and I don't really know what the problem is.

It is worth noting that internet works perfectly :-)

I attached a screenshot. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Try changing port in settings

Comment: @PratikaRana to which value?

Comment: As mention you are facing this problem after you change the internet provider, so kindly check with them whether they are blocking Bittorrent from their end.

Comment: @vembutech oh.. is that even legal?

Comment: I am not aware of legal laws of Italy. I believe just check with them will not create legal issue.

Comment: You are most likely having your traffic "shaped" during certain hours, my ISP does the same.

Comment: @vembutech I meant, is it legal to block bittorrent? or specific sites for what matters :) Probably you're not familiar with italian legislation but I think it will not be too different in this regard with the american laws :-)